# ZK show progress percentage

Tags: event-handling, progress-bar, zk

I have a ZK event handler in Java that may work slowly, and I want to show the progress on the client like this:

```
public void onClick$btnAddOrders() {
    List<Order> orders = getOrders();
    int numberOfOrder =  orders.size();
    for (int i=0; i< numberOfOrder; i++){
        addOrder(orders.get(i));
        showOnTheGui(i + " of " + numberOfOrder + " orders are processed");
    }
}
```

As I observed, these kind of notifications will displayed only when my event handler returned.

Is there any way in the free ZK editions that solves it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [timer](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/server_push/timer) to your screen. Start your timer before your `for` loop and update the screen via the `onTimer` event. Stop your timer before exiting your method.

Comment: I use ZK7 and GenericForwardComposer with autowired event listener methods like public void onClick$btnSave(). I've also put the public void onTimer$saveProgressTimer() method into this Controller but I noticed that the onTimer event handler method is not called while onClick$btnSave() is running. Even if I start the timer when loading he page. How can I fix that?

Comment: And of course, thank you for your comment! We use Timer already in the project, but there the Timer repeats some activity AFTER the event handling method finishes (i.e. checks the result of an asynchron operation).

Comment: You're going to need to run one of those processes, either the timer or the order processing, in a separate thread.

Comment: The problem is that these processes are triggered by ZK. As I see, onTimer event is also an AJAX request, like onClick event for the Save button. It looks like ZK send no onTimer request to the server until the onClick request no answer has.Can ZK work with parallel AJAX requests?

Comment: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Guide/Fundamental_ZK/Basic_Concepts/Architecture_Overview writes:
ZK AU Engine pipelines ZK requests into queues on a basis of one queue per desktop. Therefore, requests for the same desktop are processed sequentially.

Comment: My next try will be: block the GUI in onClick$btnSave(), start an asynchron method that do the long work and return from onClick$btnSave(), and update the the GUI regularly from the onTimer() method. The onTimer() do also the reactivation the GUI when the asynch method get feedback.

Comment: I accepted this answer with the additional note that we need a new thread for the event handler if we want regularly update the GUI during the run of this event handler. We have done it using Spring's @Asynch